# Convert str to dict

Tags: python, json, windows, python-3.x

I know this question has already been asked and answered and i tried some of them but none worked in my project

json.load/json.load/ast/demjson all give me error in file:

```
file = open("C:/Users/" + getpass.getuser() + "/Wiappro/name.txt").read()
file = ast.literal_eval(file)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Code\Python 5.5.4\Programmes\Messagerie\client.py", line 93, in <module>
    file = ast.literal_eval(file)
  File "D:\Code\Python 5.5.4\lib\ast.py", line 46, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "D:\Code\Python 5.5.4\lib\ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 0
```

and

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Code\Python 5.5.4\Programmes\Messagerie\client.py", line 93, in <module>
    file = json.loads(file)
  File "D:\Code\Python 5.5.4\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "D:\Code\Python 5.5.4\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "D:\Code\Python 5.5.4\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

and

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Code\Python 5.5.4\Programmes\Messagerie\client.py", line 93, in <module>
    file = demjson.decode(file)
  File "D:\Code\Python 5.5.4\lib\site-packages\demjson.py", line 5699, in decode
    return_stats=(return_stats or write_stats) )
  File "D:\Code\Python 5.5.4\lib\site-packages\demjson.py", line 4915, in decode
    raise errors[0]
demjson.JSONDecodeError: No value to decode
```

and I dont understand why json.loads/ast/demjson all worked on my interpreter ??

Comment: You should show the contents of `file`.  Otherwise, one can only guess.

Comment: sorry i forgot it's an empty dict : {}

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work but I don't know why it don't work with

```
file = open("C:/Users/" + getpass.getuser() + "/Wiappro/name.txt").read()
file = ast.literal_eval(file)
```

nor with

```
file = open("C:/Users/" + getpass.getuser() + "/Wiappro/name.txt")
file = ast.literal_eval(file.read())
```

but worked with

```
file = open("C:/Users/" + getpass.getuser() + "/Wiappro/name.json")
read = file.read()
read = ast.literal_eval(read))
```

I hope it will be usefull for other people